# buscar cadena de texto en campo MySQL

Tags: mysql

Amigos:

Tengo una BD en MySQL y decidí guardar una cadena de texto en un campo de tipo varchar. Pero ahora deseo realizar un select para obtener una subcadena, y no encuentro la forma de escribirla adecuadamente.

FormadePago
1/100/2/200

el campo se llama formadepago, y contiene una cadena que incluye "/" en mi caso el 1/100 indica que la forma de pago 1 fue hecha con 100 pesos, y tambien con la forma de pago 2, otros 200.

Al realizar un select para listar por ejemplo los $100 que corresponde a la forma de pago 1, pensé escribir lo siguiente:

```
select * from ventas where formadepago like '%1/%';
```

pero haciendo eso no me lista aquellos con las formas de pago 1, ya que tambien incluye los siguientes valores

formadepago
1/100/11/200

es decir no toma en cuenta solo el valor 1 sino todos aquellos que incluyan el 1.

alguna idea

Comment: Por aclarar un poco la pregunta, quieres hacer un select que te muestre todos los registros donde el campo formadepago contenga el 1/ unicamente o te sirve que tenga el 1/ pero también el 2/?

Comment: quiero listar por ejemplo todas las cantidades que correspondan en este caso a la forma de pago 1, en el ejemplo tengo 1/100/2/200, pero puede darse el caso que sea 3/100/1/100 y ahí por ejemplo necesito listar el 100 que corresponde al pago 1, o sea /1/ pero cuando esta al inicio puede ser 1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me preparé una BD de prueba en la cual guardé estos campos:

```
ID  formadepago
1   1100
2   1/100
3   1/100
4   1/100/2/100
```

Si lo que quieres es sacar todos los que contengan la cadena ***1/***, con esta query te debería valer:

```
SELECT formadepago from ventas WHERE formadepago LIKE '%1/%';
```

Por el contrario, si quieres mostrar única y exclusivamente los que contengan el ***1/***, sería esta query:

```
SELECT formadepago from ventas WHERE formadepago LIKE '%1/%' AND formadepago NOT LIKE '%2/%';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, fue de muchisima ayuda, aunque al final lo que hice fue hacer una funcion que me permitiera hacer una subcadena a partir de los registros, con esa funcion logre obtener una tabla donde por separado me coloca el tipo 1 y su cantidad 100 por ejemplo.